# Js Conditional (ternary) operator strange behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Qn regarding 2nd challenge of https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/choosing-the-state-structure

My code for updating "pack" doesnt work when using ternary operator. But when I use normal if else statements, it works:

ternary operator:

```
  const packed = items.reduce((acum, cur, i) => {
    console.log(`Index: ${i}, packed: ${cur.packed}, Before:${acum}, Addition: ${cur.packed ? 1 : 0}`);
    return acum + cur.packed ? 1 : 0;
  }, 0);
```

If else version:

```
  const packed = items.reduce((acum, cur) => {
    if (cur.packed) return acum + 1
    else return acum;
  }, 0);
  console.log(packed);
```

Full code (official suggested ans, my ans is the same as this except the "pack" part)

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import AddItem from './AddItem.js';
import PackingList from './PackingList.js';

let nextId = 3;
const initialItems = [
  { id: 0, title: 'Warm socks', packed: true },
  { id: 1, title: 'Travel journal', packed: false },
  { id: 2, title: 'Watercolors', packed: false },
];

export default function TravelPlan() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialItems);

  const total = items.length;
  const packed = items
    .filter(item => item.packed)
    .length;

  function handleAddItem(title) {
    setItems([
      ...items,
      {
        id: nextId++,
        title: title,
        packed: false
      }
    ]);
  }

  function handleChangeItem(nextItem) {
    setItems(items.map(item => {
      if (item.id === nextItem.id) {
        return nextItem;
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    }));
  }

  function handleDeleteItem(itemId) {
    setItems(
      items.filter(item => item.id !== itemId)
    );
  }

  return (
    <>  
      <AddItem
        onAddItem={handleAddItem}
      />
      <PackingList
        items={items}
        onChangeItem={handleChangeItem}
        onDeleteItem={handleDeleteItem}
      />
      <hr />
      <b>{packed} out of {total} packed!</b>
    </>
  );
}
```

Expected a "pack" to count the number of packed items, but always return 1 when using ternary operator, regardless of the initial value (i tried to set it to 1000 and it still returned 1)

Comment: They aren't the same condition. The ternary should be `return cur.packed ? acum + 1 : acum;` to match your `if` statement. If you need clarity on ternary syntax see the docs: [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: voting to close as typo/not reproducable.

Comment: Yeah they are not exactly the same condition, but they should produce the same outcome right?

Comment: why would you expect them to produce the same output? if `cur.packed === false` and `acum === 1` the ternary will evaluate `true` (acum + cur.packed == 1+false == 1+0 == 1 == true), while your `if` would evaluate `false` (false == false).

Comment: Ok thanks guys i figured it out.

its coz of operator precedence, the + operator gets carried out before ? ... : ...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: I totally thought js would carry out ... ? ... : ... before addition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct version using ternary

```
 const packed = items.reduce((acum, cur, i) => {
    console.log(`Index: ${i}, packed: ${cur.packed}, Before:${acum}, Addition: ${cur.packed ? 1 : 0}`);
    return cur.packed ? acum + 1 : acum;
  }, 0);
```